# empty return preg_split [how]?

Tags: php, preg-split

i have string like this

```
$string = '$foo$wow$123$$$ok$';
```

i want to return empty string and save string in array like this

```
0 = foo
1 = wow
2 = 123
3 = 
4 =
5 = ok
```

i use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, i know when make `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` return is not empty, but i want any result empty, i want my result save in variable array like in `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` with `$chars[$i];`

this is my preg_split :

```
$chars = preg_split('/[\s]*[$][\s]*/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
     echo $i.' = '.$chars[$i];
}
```

i want, my result show with looping. no in object loop  i want pure this looping:

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
     echo $i.' = '.$chars[$i];
}
```

to show my result.

how i use this preg_split, 
thanks for advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use explode

```
$str = '$foo$wow$123$$$ok$';
$res = explode ("$",$str);

print_r($res);


Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => foo
    [2] => wow
    [3] => 123
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => ok
    [7] => 
)
```

Comment: i want in array variable,  and array variable is $chars[$i] with looping

Comment: @insomniart Look at the print_r output.  From your original code above, I wondered if you knew about [`print_r()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), `var_dump()`..

Comment: If you don't want the empty `[0],[7]` keys, to `trim($str, '$')`

Comment: i want in echo not print_r

Comment: yeah.. because i want make 

`for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){
     echo $i.' = '.$chars[$i];
}`

Comment: try this : foreach($res as  $key=>$val){ echo $key.' = '.$val;}

Comment: not in object loop, i want pure `for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){ echo $i.' = '.$chars[$i]; }`

because i make many code with this loop. i want no change many code.
any solution.

Comment: for($i=0;$i<=count($res);$i++){ echo $i.' = '.$res[$i]; }

Comment: @insomniart So if you want to echo in a loop, then do so.  Your question was about how to split the string correctly, which Prasanth has shown you how to do. It is up to you to write your loop appropriately, which you already know how to do. `print_r()` is a debugging and demonstration tool.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra, excellent, how i trim 0 and the last result ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, ok i'm sorry before,

Comment: If you want to remove all the null values write this code before your for loop  $res = array_flip(array_flip($res));

Answer (score 0):

Using explode adds the empty entrys to the front and the back.

This one matches the tc's expected output:

```
$str = '$foo$wow$123$$$ok$';
preg_match_all("@(?<=\\$)[^\$]*(?=\\$)@", $str, $res);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => wow
        [2] => 123
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => ok
    )
```